# Know of a good migration plan for SSRS 2005 reports?

Tags: reporting-services, migration, reportingservices-2005

Traditionally, our plucky team of developers have always migrated our own reports into production.  This task is now being taken up by our support staff, who'll need detailed instructions to do so.

We have always deployed straight from VS2005, which can be made available to the new migrators.  Is there a better way to migrate these reports without VS2005?

Also, we need to provide some backup and rollback instructions.  Have to confess, SSRS reports are probably the only thing I haven't backed up prior to a migration ( I normally take the "hey, they're only reports!" view ).  Does anyone know of a good resource which covers backup of reports prior to deployment of replacements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this, it will backup all your reports using a script.  I've used for migrating reports between servers.  If you open the script file that it generates, you'll get a good idea how to generate your won scripts that you run using the RS.exe utility built into SSRS.
http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62